# Entity Framework Code First Migrations Multiple Project Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-migrations

Is it possible to have migrations for inherited classes in separate projects? Example:

```
DBProject
  -> MyContext
  -> Service (entity/table)
       -> Fields for all Services
MyServiceProject
  -> MyService : DBProject.Service
       -> FieldSpecificToMyService
```

Using TPH (all records stored in Services table), is that a valid pattern/structure and is it possible to do with EF Code First Migrations?  If so, how might I go about doing that?

I've tried adding migrations to MyServiceProject pointing to DBProject as the startup project, etc, but it doesn't pick up FieldSpecificToMyService as a change to model (unless I did it completely wrong).

I've tried adding a MyServiceProjectContext to MyServiceProject that inherits from MyContext and adding a migration; does not pick up the change.

I've tried going the Shared Project route, but that failed completely, likely due to my lack of understanding.